# Show columns chosen in Excel form

Tags: forms, vba, excel

Do you know whether it is possible to create a form in Excel in which a user could choose columns he/she needs to be shown?

For example I have a very wide excel file (more than 100 columns).

Once I need to open only certain columns (e.g. A, B, E, H, O) and another time the other ones (e.g. C, E, H, J).

I think that a form to choose specified columns would be more user friendly when working on the file with larger group of people but I've never created one in Excel.

Do you know how to start with this matter? And, first of all, is it possible in Excel to do such a form?

Comment: Everything is possible! I'd start by creating a class for Custom checkboxes+labels to be added to the UF at run time and the rest should be pretty easy then! ;)

Comment: Hi, it's possible but is it really *necessary*? Couldn't you just have a few extra sheets which display output differently for different users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited** to properly handle last OP's request in comments

you could add a `UserForm` to be launched at every relevant sheet activation

Add a `UserForm` (called `UserForm1`) with one ListBox (`ListBox1`) and one button (`CommandButton1`)

set `ListBox1` `MultiSelect` property to `fmMultiSelectMulti`

then add this code to `UserForm1` code pane:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long

    With Me.ListBox1
        If .ListCount > 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                If .Selected(i) Then Columns(.List(i, 0)).Hidden = False
            Next
            ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1).Select
        End If
    End With
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim col As Range
    Dim iCol As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        ReDim Data(1 To .UsedRange.Columns.Count, 1 To 2)
        For Each col In .UsedRange.Columns
            iCol = iCol + 1
            Data(iCol, 1) = Split(col.Address(, False), "$")(0)
            Data(iCol, 2) = .Cells(2, col.Column).Value
        Next
    End With
    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "0;30"
        .List = Data
    End With
End Sub
```

then add this code to your worksheet code pane

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    With UserForm1
        .Show
    End With
    Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works exactly like I need to. One more question - columns in ListBox are named A, B, C, D, etc. Do you know how to name them from the cell values in the second row?

Comment: you are welcome. see edited answer for having row 2 values listed

Comment: Could you double check the code? When running the code after changes I have a "Run time error '13' Type mismatch" error message. Thank you

Comment: see edited code. you have to 1) set listbox with two columns 2) and fill the first with worksheet columns indexes and the second with corresponding 2nd row content 3) hide the first column (`ColumnWidth=0`) 4) at button clicking use the listbox first column content to retrieve columns to hide indexes